# Maybe bug in rapidxml - but I'm not sure how to fix

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml

I noticed the rapidxml parses illegal `<<element/>` to an element named `<element`, instead of producing an error.

I think the problem is the definition of `lookup_node_name`. The comment is

```
//  Node name (anything but space \n \r \t / > ? \0)
```

What I understand from the [w3.org specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name) is that a name can have letters, numbers, and a few other characters.

I'm not sure what will be a correct fix. Any suggestions?

Comment: Without posting the code, there is nothing much anyone can do for you.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the rapidxml code, `lookup_node_name` is a lookup table of valid name characters, and as the comment says, only a specific few are prohibited.

I'd try adding '< to the list of prohibited characters by setting the lookup entry for ASCII char 0x3C from 0 to 1. ie, on the line relating to chars 0x30..0x3f, change it from this...

```
      // 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
...
         1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  // 3
```

to this:

```
         1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  // 3
```

That may work for you, but I haven't tried it. I see you've tried to contact the developer via sourceforge, which is probably the best approach...

Comment: It will work for this particular input, true, ... but I'd still love a response from the developer; especially if I want to submit a fix.